# Executing memoized function return function but not the result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adapt the memoize function to the small utility method, however, I am doing something wrong and would appreciate if someone can suggest why :)

```js
const config = {
    14340: 1195,
    15774: 1226,
    17208: 1257,
    18642: 1288,
    20076: 1319
}

const memoize = (fn) => {
    let cache = {}
    
    return (...args) => {
        let cacheKey = args.map(n => n.toString() + '+').join('')
        if (cacheKey in cache) {
            return cache[cacheKey]
        } else {
            let result = args.reduce((acc, curr) => fn(acc, curr), 0);
            cache[cacheKey] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
}

function _getMaxValue(config) {
    const keys = Object.keys(config)
        .map((k) => parseInt(k, 10))
        .sort();
  
    return config[keys[keys.length - 1].toString()];
}

const getMaxValue = (config) => memoize(_getMaxValue)

const _add = (a, b) => {
    return a + b
}
const add = memoize(_add)

console.log(getMaxValue(config)) // memoize return block
console.log(add(1, 2)) // 3
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly do you want to accomplish with this code you pasted, and how the current result is different from your desired one? It's really difficult to figure out just from this snippet.

Comment: What is `let result = args.reduce((acc, curr) => fn(acc, curr), 0)` supposed to do and why?